# Using d3.json doesn't work. I think it doesn't wait the request, but i don't know. Have you got any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the code:

```
async function readData() {
    await d3.json("edge_index.txt", function (error, links) {
        if (error) throw error;
        links = links;
    });
}
```

console.log(links) i get undefined.

links is undefined
Why ?

The file has this inside:

```
[{"source":0, "target":1},
{"source":0, "target":1},
{"source":0, "target":2},
{"source":0, "target":3},
{"source":1, "target":4},
{"source":1, "target":5},
{"source":1, "target":6},
{"source":1, "target":7},
{"source":1, "target":8},
{"source":1, "target":9}]
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/d3-js-json-function/

the call back function only uses 1 variable (d) instead of 2 (error,links)

then double check the existence of `edge_index.txt` is in the right place you are referencing from this script.

Comment: I've solved with:     readData().then(function () {
        console.log(links);
    });